# Composite design pattern and empty overrides

Tags: java, design-patterns, composite

In Composite design pattern we handle the hierarchies in the manner as shown in the UML below.

[image: Composite design pattern]

But when you look at the **Leaf** class in the above figure you see it has empty implementations of  **addComponent, removeComponent and getChild** since these methods do not apply for the Leaf node. What i really need to know is that is there any way around that we don't have to implement empty/no-op methods?

Update : Ok, i removed the Liskov's principle part since it's now clear to me. But it still does not clarify why the **Leaf** node need to force-implement the three methods and is there a way that it does not have to? I think there is another principle that states that subclasses should not be forced to implement methods which are unnecessary. My main concern are implementation of three methods for the Leaf node and you can think about this scenario in any parent-child structure, not necessarily Composite pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `addComponent()` `removeComponent()` and `getChild()` methods only make sense for a `Composite`. Thus they should not be declared in the `Component`'s API.

Nevertheless the empty implementations in the `Leaf` do not break the Liskov's substituation principle as long the `Leaf`s will behave as the `Component` defines it. I think this will be true in your case.

Furthermore you can find a good example of how a composite pattern can be implemented in java swing. Take a look at [java.awt.Component](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html) and [java.awt.Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html).

**EDIT**

> What i really need to know is that is there any way around that we don't have to implement empty/no-op methods?

Make the `Component` an abstract class instead of an interface and implement the no-op methods for `addComponent()` `removeComponent()` and `getChild()` there.

```
public abstract class Component {

     public abstract doOperation(); // still need to be implemented by subclasses


     /**
      * Empty stub method. Subclasses may override it.
      */
     public void addComponent(Component comp){
     }

     public void removeComponent(Component comp){
     }

     public Component getChild(int index){
         return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: This does mean that a Composite will either need to expose two collections (one for leaf nodes, one for child composites) or you will need to use something like the visitor pattern for tree traversal.

Comment: @heinrichj With a composite pattern you want to handle a collection of elements as if it is one element itself. Thus if you invoke `doOperation` on an object that is a `Composite` it will just iterate through all it's children and invoke `doOperation()`. It does not need to know if the child is a composite or not.

Comment: @heinrichj Nevertheless you can of course use a visitor pattern in combination with a composite pattern. I only want to say that it is not absolutely necessary.

Comment: @RenéLink ok. i updated my question. do you have anything about that?

Comment: @RenéLink yes. i think this is exactly i was hoping for :)